# difference between JavaScript bit-wise operator code and Python bit-wise operator code

Tags: javascript, python, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have converted JavaScript code which uses bit-wise operators in that code to Python code, but there is one problem when i do this in JavaScript and Python

```
412287 << 10
```

then I get this **422181888** same results in both languages. but when i do this in both

```
424970184 << 10
```

then i get different results in both of the languages **1377771520** in JavaScript and **435169468416** in Python

can anybody help me with this?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the JavaScript equivalent value then what you can do is :

```
import ctypes

print(ctypes.c_int(424970184 << 10 ^ 0).value)
```

Output:

```
1377771520
```

Comment: Hi @Achilles thank you for your answer, I have tried this and it is working, will it work for >> operator as well?

Comment: Yes,this  would get the same overflow behavior as Javascript.

Comment: Thanks @Achilles, last question will it work for all bit-wise operators? like ^ operator?

Comment: Yes it should work without a problem as it's only limiting the unlimited integer precision of Python.

Comment: Thank you @Achilles for your all replies, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin), in javascript the bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints, and your second example overflows the 32 bit capacity, so the python equivalent would be:

```
(424970184 << 10) & 0x7FFFFFFF
```

(you get a "modulo"/"masked" value with the signed 32 bit integer mask, not the actual value)

In Python there's no limit in capacity for integers, so you get the actual value.

Comment: Afaik, JavaScript uses 54 bits to represent numbers.

Comment: but `(424970184 << 10) & (2**53-1)` yields `435169468416`

Comment: Ah but the bitwise operators operate on 32 bits. But an int itself has storage for 54 bits.

Comment: just checked my self. Thanks for pointing this out, my answer would have been incorrect without that info.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: JavaScript numbers are actually double-precision (8 byte) floats, not ints. Doubles can represent integers up to 2^53 exactly, just like a 54-bit int could, but that's not what they are.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-François Fabre for your fast reply!